# How do I chain Singles in Rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java

I had this:

```
    @Override
    public Single<JsonObject> getUser(String token) {
    return tokenManager.getTokenInfo(token)
        .map(userInfo -> userRepo.findOne(userInfo));
    }
```

But the compiler complains that `Single<Single<JsonObject>>` cannot be converted to `Single<JsonObject>`. The problem is, userRepo.findOne returns a single, so the .map() returns a single that resolves to a single, rather than the value. Is there a way to flatten this? Like with JavaScript promises where if you had a promise that resolves to a promise, a subscriber to the first promise recieves the value of the second promise, rather than the promise itself.
I am currently settled with this:

```
public Single<JsonObject> getUser(String token) {
    return Single.create(emitter -> {
        tokenManager.getTokenInfo(token)
            .subscribe(userInfo -> userRepo.findOne(userInfo)
            .subscribe(user -> emitter.onSuccess(user),
                emitter::onError),
                emitter::onError);
    });

    }
```

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with this API, but the operation you're looking for is usually called `flatMap`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- If only I didn't need the userInfo in the map(). I would have used flatMap.